# How to access tags like `sphinx-build -t abc` in `conf.py`?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

According to Sphinx' documentation there is a `tags` object available in `conf.py` ([master](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#conf-tags)). However, I get: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has'`

`conf.py`:

```py
if tags.has('abc'):
```

`pip list`:

```
Package      Version
------------ ---------
Sphinx       5.0.2
```

How to access tags like `sphinx-build -t abc` in `conf.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `'abc'` in `conf.py` like this:

```
if 'abc' in tags.tags.keys():
  # do some magic
```

or if you need to check the boolean value of your tag:

```
if tags.tags.get('abc', False):
  # do some magic
```

`tags` get injected by Sphinx into the `conf.py` during a build and is available without any import.